# Ethernet does not work with Ubuntu 14.04 on Beaglebone Black

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, ethernet, beagleboneblack

I just got new Ubuntu 14.04 on my BBB, and I cannot connect to the Ethernet. I have been researching a lot, but no posts that could help me solve my problem. By the way, I only have the command line, so I do not have GUI. If anyone could help, that would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Wrong site. This one is for programming questions. You're looking for [ubuntu.se] or [su] instead. Please review the site guidelines before posting at any of the [se] sites to ensure you've chosen the proper one. You can find the guidelines for this site in the [help].

Answer (score 0):

Well, after a day of working on getting Ethernet to work with my BBB and Ubuntu, I have figured it out. If you guys have this problem, just keep your internet cable plugged in while you are flashing new image to the BBB. It will automatically set up required dependencies. So, I just flashed OS again with the cable plugged in, and I have got the Ethernet now.